# How to convert Blender physics animation to Collada?

Tags: scenekit, blender, collada

I need animated box, so it looks like when jelly jiggles.

I need to export it to .dae (collada), so I would be able to add it to Xcode - SceneKit.

I tried everything I found, but I can not get the solution.
I tried to animate it by simulating physics, but collada does not support that, so I tried to animate it with skeleton aswell, but blender collada export does not support skeletal skin animation, so that also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you animate the "jiggle" box directly in SceneKit with the help of a shader modifier. No need to import a simple geometry.

See an example in this blog post: [SceneKit Shaders Intro](https://medium.com/@maxxfrazer/arkit-scenekit-shaders-intro-99df65137006).